# MSChart XValue Problem

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I am using MS Chart -Pie to display Page name and its record status count in Pie Chart [MS Chart].

Page Name Valid  InValid
xxx             12       30
yyy             17       20

Number of pages is 20.

Problem: If the XValue is more than 9 means all the records are not getting displayed. Only few random records are displaying.

Code:

```
   <asp:Chart ID="chrtMaster" runat="server" Height="656px" Width="807px" BackColor="WhiteSmoke"
                        BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BackSecondaryColor="White">
                        <Legends>
                            <asp:Legend BackColor="WhiteSmoke" Name="Legend1">
                            </asp:Legend>
                        </Legends>
                        <Series>
                            <asp:Series Name="Valid" Legend="Legend1" XValueMember="MasterTable" YValueMembers="Valid"
                                YValuesPerPoint="1" YValueType="Int32" CustomProperties="PointWidth=1.5" Color="220, 65, 140, 240">
                            </asp:Series>
                            <asp:Series Name="Pending" Legend="Legend1" XValueMember="MasterTable" YValueMembers="Pending"
                                YValuesPerPoint="1" YValueType="Int32" CustomProperties="PointWidth=1.5" Color="220, 252, 180, 65">
                            </asp:Series>
                            <asp:Series Name="Disabled" Legend="Legend1" XValueMember="MasterTable" YValueMembers="Disabled"
                                YValuesPerPoint="1" YValueType="Int32" CustomProperties="PointWidth=1.5" Color="220, 224, 64, 10">
                            </asp:Series>
                        </Series>
                        <ChartAreas>
                            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" BackSecondaryColor="White"
                                BorderColor="64, 64, 64, 64" ShadowColor="Transparent">
                                <Area3DStyle LightStyle="Realistic" WallWidth="0" />
                            </asp:ChartArea>
                        </ChartAreas>
                    </asp:Chart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
chrtMaster.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```